# Apply real-time database rules on Firebase admin sdk

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin, firebase-security

I create API that used firebase client sdk to authorize user by real-time database rules, but the api return "PERMISSION_DENIED" when i used generated token by firebase app.

this is short code for my api:

```
// GET {{url}}/users

import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

// admin sdk to verify generated token.
const userAuth = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(accessToken); // return user object, no problem with that.
const user = await firebase.database().ref(`users/${userAuth.uid}/`).once('value'); // this causes "PERMISSION_DENIED" when fetch data from database.
```

this sample of my db rules:

```
{
 "rules": {
  "users": {
    ".read": "auth !== null"
  },
 },
}
```

I used firebase client sdk to apply db rule on it, and i don't want to used admin sdk because it have full admin privileges.
So how can i solved this problem ?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're asking. It seems a bit like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish in this script?

Comment: i need admin SDK to access the Realtime Database with the permission of specific user by his token.
(i can't initialize admin sdk multiple time.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is you need the admin sdk to verify the sent token, then you need to initialiase the admin sdk with `databaseAuthVariableOverride` based on decoded token!

Comment: Also you can't initialiase admin sdk multiple time!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the admin SDK to access the Realtime Database with the permission of `userAuth`, you'll want to set `databaseAuthVariableOverride` when initializing the `FirebaseApp`. For full details and code samples, see [authenticate with limited privileges](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#authenticate-with-limited-privileges)

Comment: I can't verify user by his token if i not initialized admin sdk before by using "verifyIdToken", i try your solution before and i got error "Initializing firebase multiple times."

Answer (score 0):

admin.auth().verifyIdToken just check if token validate, It does not guarantee endorsement for the next functions. So you need to use firebase admin sdk instead of client api.

```
await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(accessToken).then(() => {
  //You code here
  admin.database().ref(`users/${userAuth.uid}/`).once('value');
}).catch(err => {
  //Token invalid
})
```